# How do I tune Graphite to not drop data points?

Tags: graphite

I have a graphite instance which is taking in a little over 100k metrics per minute.  Some servers have gaps in their metrics, others do not.  Individual servers have some metrics with a lot of gaps, others with few or no gaps.

The gaps seem to be on a very rhythmic basis.  For example, sending CPU at 1/sec, it would send 7, drop 3, send 7, drop 4, back and forth.  When I sent them in at one every 10 seconds, it would drop one roughly every 3 minutes (18 data points).

Because the rhythm varies from metric to metric, server to server, I find it hard to blame the carbon-cache for the missing metrics.  If the data were coming in too fast, why wouldn't the dropped metrics be spread evenly among all metrics?  Besides, the computer isn't really even breaking a sweat, and the disk isn't all that busy, either.

My questions are:

- How do I prove that the diamond collectors are (or are not) sending all the data points?
- How do I get carbon to tell me that it has dropped data points (if it did)?
- What do I need to measure on the graphite server to know when it is unable to take any more metrics?

UPDATE:

I learned that to prove the diamond collector is working correctly, I can run it in the foreground by typing

```
diamond -f -l
```

I also discovered that there were errors that were not making it into the logs.  When I disabled the offending collectors, the gaps were reduced if not eliminated.

Comment: If I remember correctly then graphite events are sent via udp. In that case,  messages could just get lost on the network layer

Comment: Our carbon instance has ENABLE_UDP_LISTENER = False, so it's not likely to be caused by that.

Comment: Just to verify that it's not carbon-cache, you could direct traffic to netcat  running as server and view incoming commands in stdout or dump them to file.

    nc -lk 2003